# Custom small icon for notification for phonegap android plugin (Sencha Touch 2)

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, android-notifications, android-resources

I am building a custom phonegap/cordova android plugin which shows notifications (which is only a part of my plugin). I am using the android notifications builder for the same. However, for the notifications builder I need to use setSmallIcon() to set the notification icon. However, this requires a resource id integer. For the big icon, I could use the bitmap from my Sencha Touch App resources location, however for the small icon, I do not know how I can get the resource id of that. Is there a way I can do that?